# Javascript dynamic assigning parametrized function to onclick

Tags: javascript, function, dynamic, onclick

I have to dynamically create series of links that when clicked - change some others elements properties (src, class, text), basing on some data taken from elsewhere (json).

I've got such a piece of code:

```
  // this is data I need processed
  screenshots = report_data.screenshots;
  // for each I'd like to create a link
  for (var i=0; i < screenshots.length; i++) {
      document.write('<a href="" onclick="{document.getElementById(\'the_screenshot\').src = \''+ screenshots[i].screenshotFile + '\'; ' + 'return false;}">' + screenshots[i].screenshotTitle + '</a>');
  });
```

However proper escaping all those characters took me two hours.
I'd like to place there a call to elsewhere defined parametrized function.
Then I'd only have to input the parameters.

I tried of many various combinations of what I've found on stackoverflow.com
leading me to a terrible headache.

Please, help.

Comment: Rather than writing the HTML with JavaScript, why not have the HTML in the page by default but use CSS styling to display none or display inline your various links. That way, all you have to do is DOM manipulation instead of dynamic HTML creation.

Comment: You can use an event handler like jQuery's [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live) (or its new, non-deprecated replacement) to catch clicks on links of a given class. You can store the new `src` in a `data` attribute. Also, if you use proper DOM manipulation methods, like `document.createElement`, you shouldn't have too much of an issue with escaping.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I can't uses css here to hide/display links, 'cause I don't know how many links will be necessary, hence I use external data source.

Comment: DOM manipulation methods on the other hand looks to have required potential. Thanks for that hint arxanas. I'll check that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accidentally, after hours of trying and retrying I asked my friend and his wise head told me to do it somewhat more sophisticated way:

- Create a parametrized function in plain javascript.
- Use closures - assign to onclick only the anonymous function that calls the above mentioned with adequate parameter.
- Create the pattern string of the tag to pass to the document.write(html) with variable-like section for onclick function code.
- Use string.replace(A,toB) function: create a string with function code to assign.
- Do the same trick with the function parameter if required.
- Pass the filled in pattern to document.writa(html) function.

The final solution looks like this (may be not exactly same, but the idea is pointed):

```
// function to call by closure
onLinkClick = function(SRC) {
    document.getElementById('the_screenshot').src = SRC;
    // and here one can place as much code as he needs // plain js
    // and I did it
}

// this is data I need processed
screenshots = report_data.screenshots;
for (var i=0; i < screenshots.length; i++) {
    // first enlist every basic part with it's inner parameters as text
    var pattern = '<a href="" onclick=ONCLICK>TEXT</a>'
    var onclick = '(function (){onLinkClick(PARAM); return false;})()';
    var text = screenshots[i].screenshotTitle;
    var param = screenshots[i].screenshotFile;
    // now inject them - without any more escaping via replace
    onclick = onclick.replace('PARAM', param);
    pattern = pattern.replace('ONCLICK', onclick);
    pattern = pattern.replace('TEXT', text);
    document.write(pattern);
});
```

This way the code looks much more elegant than on the first approach.
I hope this helps those, who will have to face javascript in future.

One more thing, I used to think a detail, but it came out to be a really serious: syntax. To make a closure function do it's work:

- write a function just like usual
- surround it with parentheses
- follow it by a another pair of empty parentheses

like this:

```
(function(){return false;})()
```

Now it's an anonymous function, not just an anonymous function call. And now it works.